# React Complex Array, how to extract values?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, dictionary, foreach

I'm a newbie and I hope to don't ask nothing silly, but I'm getting crazy to find the solution!
For my app I'm using a public API
the part I need is this one(short version cause it's huge)

```
{
  "artists": [
    {
      "name": "Artist 1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Artist 2",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Artist 3",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Artist 4",
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

The render:

```
render() {
    const {
      name,
      id
    } = this.props.record;
```

The function:

```
 [artistsArray].forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(item.artists[0].name);
    });
```

Output:

```
return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-3">
            {name} {id}
        </h1>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

The problem is that I can't get the name and the id.
`console.log(item); console.log(item.artists[0].name);` give me error or **undefined**.
How can I do?

Looked simple but I can get out of this. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit going on here!

Here's an example of how I would accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
const artists = [
  {
    "name": "Artist 1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Artist 2",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Artist 3",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Artist 4",
    "id": 4
  }
]

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        artists.map((artist, artistIndex) => {
          return (
            <div key={artistIndex} className="container">
              <h1 className="display-3">
                {artist.name}  {artist.id}
              </h1>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

You seem to be confusing a few different syntaxes, i'd go back to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) and take a closer look if I were you

Answer (score 0):

Based in what we could grasp from your code:

The list is an `object` that contains an `array` of `objects` ala `{'artisans' => [{}, {}, {}...]}`. If this is the case you then you could do: `aristArray.artists.map((artisan) => console.log(artisan.name));`.

To make it work with React inside the JSX you should do like:

```
return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-3">
            {
              aristArray.artists.map((artisan) => artisan.name + " " + artisan.id);
            }
        </h1>
      </Fragment>
    );
 }
```

Check what [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method does, if you don't understand exactly what is going on.